# Wait for a function to finish executing before the start method stops

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

Hi I am working on game that uses random terrain and I want to spawn objects onto that terrain. To do this, I have created what I have called the Surface Populator Script.

This is the script:

```
public SurfaceSpawnerData spawnerData;

private float randomX;
private float randomZ;
private Renderer r;

void Start()
{
    r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnerData.spawnableObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].currentObjects = 0;
    }
    spawnerData.SpawnedObjects.Clear();

    SpawnObjects();
}

void Update()
{

}

void SpawnObjects()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    for (int i = 0; i < spawnerData.spawnableObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        int currentObjects = spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].currentObjects;
        int numOfObjects = spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].numberOfObjects;

        if (currentObjects != numOfObjects)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(new Vector3(randomX, r.bounds.max.y + 5f, randomZ), -Vector3.up, out hit))
            {
                randomX = Random.Range(r.bounds.min.x, r.bounds.max.x);
                randomZ = Random.Range(r.bounds.min.z, r.bounds.max.z);

                if (hit.point.y >= spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].spawnerStartHeight && hit.point.y <= spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].spawnerEndHeight)
                {
                    spawnerData.SpawnedObjects.Add(Instantiate(spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].spawnablePrefab, hit.point, Quaternion.identity));
                    spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].currentObjects += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script also gains its data from a scriptable object:

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class SurfaceSpawnerData : ScriptableObject
{
    public SpawnableObjects[] spawnableObjects;
    public List<GameObject> SpawnedObjects; 

    [System.Serializable]
    public class SpawnableObjects
    {
        public GameObject spawnablePrefab;
        public float spawnerStartHeight = 2f;
        public float spawnerEndHeight;
        public int currentObjects;
        public int numberOfObjects;
    }
}
```

This script currently works perfectly fine when placed inside the update method, however I do not want to do this due to its affect on performance. Therefore I am wondering if there is a way to stop the Unity start method from exiting until my SpawnObjects() function has stopped running. If this is not possible if you have any other ideas on how I run this only once without using the update function let me know.

I am relatively new to c# as a language and I'm sorry if there is an easy fix that I have missed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. since `SpawnObjects` is a synchronus method `Start` will not return until `SpawnObjects` finished anyway... Also what exactly do you call in `Update`?

Comment: Do you think `Start` is exiting right now before `SpawnObjects` is finished?  I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @BenRubin I'm not sure i did the best job at explaining the issue. The script is currently set to produce 10 tress and then stop this works fine if it placed inside the update method however, when placed in the start method it will only spawn 1-2 tress each time. I've also just realised it could be a possible issue with how the spawnObjects method works.

Comment: As a side note, it seems wrong that randomX and randomZ are used before they are set the first time. You might want to move them above the Physics.Raycast statement. Also you can increment by 1 by writing spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].currentObjects++ , just a matter of style though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SpawnObjects` is a synchronus method `Start` will not return until `SpawnObjects` finished anyway.

As far as I understand your issue is rather that anything from [`Physics`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) is not available during initialization (`Awake`, `OnEnable`, `Start`) but only within or after the Physics block (see [ExecutionOrder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)) so e.g. in a method like `FixedUpdate` or `Update`.

---

So to answer your question: You could use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and [`WaitForFixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html) in order to make your Instantiation:

```
void Start()
{
    r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnerData.spawnableObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].currentObjects = 0;
    }
    spawnerData.SpawnedObjects.Clear();

    StartCoroutine(DoInstantiate());
}

private IEnumerator DoInstantiate()
{
    // wait until Physics are initialized
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

    SpawnObjects();
}
```

or as you can see in [ScriptReference/Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) you can make this shorter by directly making the `Start` a routine e.g. like

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnerData.spawnableObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        spawnerData.spawnableObjects[i].currentObjects = 0;
    }
    spawnerData.SpawnedObjects.Clear();

    // wait until Physics are initialized
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

    SpawnObjects();
}
```

Comment: Thank you some overall good advice however after trying it, nothing spawns I am beginning to think the problem is actually with my SpawnObjects method.

Comment: I have now found the solution as it turns out i was missing a for loop needed to loop through the number of objects created i was only looping through the different areas in the array.